# Parse RSS pubdate to DateTime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, rss

I get this date string from an RSS:

> Wed, 16 Dec 2015 17:57:15 +0100

I need to parse into a DateTime. Ive googled and searched stack overflow and gotten to the following answer (ive tried with only one, two and four 'z' instead of three)

```
string parseFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, parseFormat,
                                    DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo,
                                    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

But I get this error:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.

Comment: http://ideone.com/glxs9G - it seems to work just fine. Show us [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your code.

Comment: Your code seems right. Perhaps it has to do with your local `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` values. With `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` will work fine.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That was it. So now i just figure out how to change the culture of the DateTime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your code to

```
  string parseFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, parseFormat,
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

As commented, your format and string matches *unless* if your `CurrentCulture` is *english-based* one. If it is not, it *can't* parse these `Wed` and `Dec` parts successfully.

On the other hand, `zzz` format specifier does not recommended for `DateTime` parsing.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zzzSpecifier);

> With `DateTime` values, the `"zzz"` custom format specifier represents the
>   signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from `UTC`,
>   measured in hours and minutes. It does not reflect the value of an
>   instance's `DateTime.Kind` property. **For this reason, the "zzz" format
>   specifier is not recommended for use with `DateTime` values.**

However, I would parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) instead of `DateTime` since you have an UTC Offset in your string like;

```
var dateString = "Wed, 16 Dec 2015 17:57:15 +0100";
string parseFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateString, parseFormat,
                                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                               DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Now, you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `{16.12.2015 17:57:15 +01:00}` which as `+01:00` `Offset` part.

[image]